# Unable to start titan server with embedded cassandra and rexter

Tags: cassandra, titan, tinkerpop, rexster

I am trying to run Titan with embedded cassandra and rexster. Downloaded Titan distribution titan-all-0.3.2 and unpacked on a linux box. After unpacking this is what i ran the command

$ ./bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties

This is what i see in the logs 
After starting RexPro services its unable to deploy and start grizzly. Has anyone had this issue?

Exception stack trace:

```
    13/10/18 14:51:31 INFO server.RexProRexsterServer: RexPro serving on port: [8184]
    Oct 18, 2013 2:51:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
    INFO: Starting application [jersey] ...
    Oct 18, 2013 2:51:31 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
    SEVERE: [jersey] Exception deploying application.  See stack trace for details.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No     WebApplication provider is present
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext.initServlets(WebappContext.java:1479)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext.deploy(WebappContext.java:265)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some packaging problems in some of the 0.3.2 zip files.  You basically need to replace a jar file or two around Jersey to get it to work (or I think use the [titan-cassandra distribution](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-cassandra-0.3.2.zip) instead of titan-all).

You can read more about the issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/aureliusgraphs/NSJOQDl13Gc/mdee0nUDQRMJ) and its solution (also reported [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/titan%2420server%24200.3.2/aureliusgraphs/KCMneS1CsJk/YbvJm7aF9GUJ)), but the answer is:

> You should be able to patch 0.3.2 by replacing this jar file in the
>   Titan lib directory:
>
> jersey-core-1.8.jar
>
> with:
>
> jersey-core-1.17
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.17/jersey-core-1.17.jar)